# Simplying vector drawable for android

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

I wish to simply a vector drawable created from a `svg` in [inkscape](https://www.wacom.com/en/products/apps-services/inkspace). According to `Android Studio` my **vector path is too long**.

I don't know how to fix it so that it'll work. The code is below, along with what the drawable is suppose to look like.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="43.844998dp"
    android:height="43.591998dp"
    android:viewportWidth="43.844998"
    android:viewportHeight="43.591998">

    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/green_8"
        android:fillAlpha="0.78039216"
        android:strokeWidth="2.64575863"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round"
        android:pathData="M15.2489,209.971 C12.7531,209.916,10.5865,211.751,10.2745,214.283 L9.66091,219.266 L4.38994,219.255 C1.66777,219.249,-0.52854,221.436,-0.53455,224.158 C-0.540523,226.88,1.64606,229.076,4.36823,229.082 L8.45091,229.092 L7.75302,234.76 L4.38993,234.753 C1.66776,234.747,-0.52854,236.933,-0.53456,239.656 C-0.540533,242.378,1.64606,244.574,4.36823,244.58 L6.54302,244.586 L6.11669,248.048 C5.78398,250.75,7.69139,253.192,10.3932,253.525 C13.095,253.858,15.5379,251.951,15.8706,249.249 L16.4421,244.607 L22.0361,244.619 L21.6139,248.047 C21.2812,250.749,23.1883,253.191,25.8901,253.524 C28.5919,253.857,31.0348,251.95,31.3675,249.248 L31.9349,244.641 L38.3859,244.655 C41.1081,244.661,43.3044,242.474,43.3104,239.752 C43.3164,237.03,41.1298,234.834,38.4076,234.828 L33.1446,234.817 L33.8427,229.149 L38.3858,229.159 C41.108,229.165,43.3043,226.978,43.3103,224.256 C43.3163,221.534,41.1297,219.338,38.4075,219.332 L35.0524,219.325 L35.525,215.487 C35.8577,212.785,33.9506,210.343,31.2488,210.01 C28.547,209.677,26.1041,211.584,25.7714,214.286 L25.1536,219.303 L19.5596,219.291 L20.028,215.488 C20.3607,212.786,18.4536,210.344,15.7518,210.011 C15.5829,209.99,15.4151,209.978,15.2487,209.975 Z M18.35,229.112 L23.944,229.124 L23.2459,234.792 L17.6522,234.78 Z" />
</vector>
```

[image]

Comment: Now you can optimize a vector using Android Studio plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12690-mike-s-idea-extensions/versions/stable/148933

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [avocado](https://github.com/alexjlockwood/avocado) to reduce the complexity and long paths.

This will optimize your vector drawable and fix the issue.

**Installation:**

```
npm install -g avocado
```

**Usage Example:**

```
avocado vector.xml
```

Here is [**before**](https://github.com/alexjlockwood/avocado#before) and [**after**](https://github.com/alexjlockwood/avocado#after) optimization of vector drawables using avocado.

Check [usage link](https://github.com/alexjlockwood/avocado#usage) for more command options.

Comment: Can it ruin how the SVG is shown? Is there an online tool for batch operations on VectorDrawable? Or a plugin for Android Studio?

Comment: Avocado can compress all files in a given path using `/path/to/svgs/*`. I've never seen it ruin an SVG. Yet...

Comment: Just in case anyone gets here, this tool seem to do the oposite you need when you get the "vector path is too long" error, because it joins paths instead of separating them into shorter ones. I had two "too long" paths and now I have one even more "too long" path

Comment: Another option is combining the online tool SVGOMG for optimizing SVG and then processing it with Avocado - results in even smaller files. https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/

Answer (score 2):

You can also minify the SVG, and then recreate the XML drawable.
For example with `svgo`: https://github.com/svg/svgo

Install with: `npm -g install svgo`

And then: `svgo original_icon.svg -o minified_icon.svg`